# Is my pothos too root-bound? -- Tiny leaves in new growth

Tags: houseplants, roots

I bought this golden Pothos a year ago and it looks great, healthy and growing well until recently. 5 weeks ago I pruned it for the first time (I am propagating the cuttings in water and those seem perfectly healthy). But now the new growth that is coming out from the vines is really tiny. Really tiny leaves! I am trying to figure out what the problem might be and wanted your opinion.

This plant has been living in the same spot for the last year, near a East facing window where it gets a bit of direct morning light but mostly indirect light. I let the soil go pretty dry before watering. I have been fertilising it for the past 2 months or so with a general liquid fertiliser every other watering. It has never been repotted and it is quite root-bound, as you can see in the picture. I left it like this because I read, and also experienced in the past, that these plants like to be root-bound. I wonder if I overshot here?

Thank you!

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Has the pot with drainage holes and roots hanging out  the bottom been sat inside the terracotta pot all this time?

Comment: Yes, the grow pot and those roots have been siting inside the terracotta pot all this time! (Both pots have drainage holes and I never let the plant sit in water.)

Answer (score 1):

Roots hanging out the bottom of a pot are a sure sign the plant needs a bigger pot and has done for some time, although a close fitting outer pot can sometimes encourage this to happen.

I don't know why you think these plants like to be rootbound, but either way, it needs a bigger pot. It's going to be difficult  because there is quite extensive root growth hanging out - you may need to break some off, but try to keep some intact. Use a pot that is 1-2 sizes larger than its current one, together with new potting soil, and preferably use an outer pot that doesn't fit quite so closely around it.

Comment: Actually i have never been able to understand , why people say that plant need to be root bound, Are they plants themselves. I know i dont want my feet clamped